# Unable to close browser using webbrowser module

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

Unable to close browser using python `webbrowser`.
I don't know how to close it.

Code is:

```
    elif 'open chrome' in query:
        Cpath = 'C:\\Users\\hi\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
        os.startfile(Cpath)
```

Comment: Can You past your code here not on screenshot ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You can use a limited version of markdown to format your questions and answers quite nicely. [Here's some formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to using Python's [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser) module to start one up, although even if you did it wouldn't help because the controller objects it creates don't support a `close()` method.

That's also true about the `os.startfile()` function you are using, and there's no option to wait for the application to close or to force it to do so.

Because of that, I suggest that you create an instance of the [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) class to start the web-browser application, because if you did, you would then have the option of calling the [`terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) (or `kill()`) method of the class instance to close it.